# Find directories within directories ending in 'l0' that do not contain '*18*' in their names

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, find

I am currently doing `find . ! -name '*18*' -name '*l0*' -type d` but it is listing all the parent directories like 'd1_l0' , 'd2_l0', 'd3_l0' etc only. I actually want subdirectories like 'd1_l0/[15*,16*,17*]', 'd2_l0/[15*,16*,17*]', 'd3_l0/[15*,16*,17*]'

Comment: Do the subdirectories also end in `*l0`? If not, the query `*l0` will not list subdirectories

Comment: im quering '\*l0\*' actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find topleveldir/ -mindepth 2 -path "*l0*" ! -path "*18*" -type d
```

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to `find` is the directory (or directories) to start at when searching. If you want to find subdirectories of all directories ending with `l0`, use a Bash wildcard to select the directories to search: `*l0`. Note that there cannot be quotes around this for the wildcard to work.

To exclude subdirectories that contain `18`, use `'*18*'`. The quotes in this case cause the wildcards not to expand before the find command.

You can also use the `-maxdepth` and `-mindepth` predicates. Replace `maxdepth` and `mindepth` with values appropriate for your query. Also, make sure to put all inclusive predicates before the `!`.

Also, use `-path` instead of `-name` to match the full path.

```sh
find *l0 -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d ! -path '*18*'
```

Comment: @MiloMinderbinder Ah, sorry, put them before the `!`. See edited answer.

Comment: im getting the same results. Tried mindepth 2 as well (which results in no output)

Comment: i guess im fundamentally wrong about find. Would you kindly explain why my command is not working as well?

Comment: i got it .. -name matches only the last part of the path. We should have used -path instead of -name if we want entire path matched. Please make this change in your answer and i will accept and upvote it

Comment: @MiloMinderbinder Updated my answer

Comment: Many many thanks for the help kind friend. However, SiegeX's answer  was the first that worked perfectly fine so i am going to accept it

Answer (score 0):

To begin, your third predicate is bad, if you want names ending in `l0` then you have to use `-name '*l0'` (without the last asterisk) and not `-name '*l0*'` (which actually means *containing the substring `'l0'`*)

It probably will be easier to do with a pipeline, through `grep(1)`, as you can have the full regexp support:

```
find . -type d | grep 'l0$' | grep -v '18[^/]*$'
```

The `find` just gets all subdirectories, the first grep conserves only the pathnames ending in `l0`, and the last `grep` just eliminates all that have the substring `18` in the last component path (the regexp `18[^/]*$` matches all `18` substrings that are followed by characters different of `/` before the end of the path, so all those paths are **eliminated** --by the `-v` option-- from the stream)